# Grouped Variant Images using alt-text w/ the "Turbo" theme | Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, thumbnails, product

Tried taking a quick stab at putting this code at the bottom of every type of "product" liquid file for Out of the Sandbox's Turbo theme for Shopify. Usually can get it to work for most other themes, with a little bit of tweaking. But the product code in this theme seems pretty robust and thus pretty complicated. I know I'm working with too big a brush here. Trying to whittle it down a bit. Anybody out there work with Turbo and grouped Variant Images with any success?

originally from Github
https://gist.github.com/carolineschnapp/d3c1af82b915e9cae82929e6486f22fe

```js
{% assign option_name = 'Color' %}

{% if product.options contains option_name %}

<script>
// Grabbing product thumbnails
// Covers: Editions, Launchpad Star, Lookbook, Kickstand, Startup, Simple, Radiance, Minimal, Supply, New Standard and many more.
var thumbnails = jQuery('img[src*="/products/"]') /* All product images */
  .not('#related-products img')                   /* Except related products, thumbnails not clickable */
  .not('a[href^="/collections/"] img')            /* Except related products */
  .not('a[href^="/products/"] img')               /* Except mini-cart products */
  .not('header img')                              /* Except mini-cart products, thumbnails not clickable */
  .not('#drawer img')                             /* Except mini-cart products, thumbnails not clickable, in Simple theme. */
  .not(':first');                                 /* Except first one, i.e the main image */
  
var optionSelect; 
{% assign option_index = 0 %}  
{% for option in product.options %}
  {% if option == option_name %}
    {% assign option_index = forloop.index0 %}  
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
  
{% if product.options.size == 1 %}
  optionSelect = '.single-option-selector';
{% else %}
  optionSelect = 'label:contains({{ option_name }}) + .single-option-selector';   
{% endif %}
  
jQuery('form[action="/cart/add"]').on('change', optionSelect, function() {
  var optionValue = $(this).val();
  thumbnails.each(function() {
    var wrapper = $(this);
    while ( wrapper.parent().children().length === 1 ) {
      wrapper = wrapper.parent();
    }
    if ( jQuery(this).attr('alt') === optionValue ) {
      wrapper.show();
    }
    else {
      wrapper.hide();
    }
  });
});    
</script>

{% endif %}
```

### Edit// Added product-description-bottom-template.liquid

---

```js
<div class="container main content">
  <a name="pagecontent" id="pagecontent"></a>

  <div class="sixteen columns">
    {% if collection.previous_product or collection.next_product or section.settings.product_breadcrumb %}
      <div class="clearfix breadcrumb-collection">
        {% if collection.previous_product or collection.next_product %}
          <div class="nav_arrows breadcrumb_text">
            {% if collection.previous_product %}
              <a href="{{ collection.previous_product }}" title="{{ 'products.general.previous_product_html' | t }}" class="breadcrumb_link"><span class="icon-left-arrow"> {{ 'products.general.previous_product_html' | t }}</span></a>
            {% endif %}
            {% if collection.previous_product and collection.next_product %}<span class="breadcrumb-divider"> | </span>{% endif %}

            {% if collection.next_product %}
              <a href="{{collection.next_product}}" title="{{ 'products.general.next_product_html' | t }}" class="breadcrumb_link">{{ 'products.general.next_product_html' | t }} <span class="icon-right-arrow"></span></a>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        {% endif %}

        {% if section.settings.product_breadcrumb %}
          <div class="breadcrumb_text" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
            <span itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a href="{{ shop.url }}" title="{{ shop.name | escape }}" itemprop="item" class="breadcrumb_link"><span itemprop="name">{{ 'general.breadcrumbs.home' | t }}</span></a></span>
            <span class="breadcrumb-divider">/</span>
            <span itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
              {% if collection %}
                <a href="{{ collection.url }}" title="{{ collection.title | escape }}" itemprop="item" class="breadcrumb_link"><span itemprop="name">{{ collection.title }}</span></a>
              {% else %}
                <a href="/collections/all" title="{{ collections.all.title }}" class="breadcrumb_link"><span>{{ collections.all.title }}</span></a>
              {% endif %}
            </span>
            <span class="breadcrumb-divider">/</span>
            {{ product.title }}
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>

  {% comment %}Check to see if sidebar should be enabled{% endcomment %}
  {% if section.blocks.size > 0 %}
    {% assign sidebar = true %}
  {% else %}
    {% assign sidebar = false %}
  {% endif %}

  {% if sidebar %}
  <div class="product">
    {% include 'sidebar' %}
   </div>
    <div class="twelve columns">
      <div class="product-{{ product.id }}">
  {% else %}
    <div class="sixteen columns">
      <div class="product-{{ product.id }}">
  {% endif %}

    <div class="section product_section clearfix js-product_section" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

      <div class="{% if sidebar %}seven{% else %}nine{% endif %} columns {% if product-images == blank %}{% if section.settings.product_images_position == 'left' %}alpha{% else %}omega{% endif %}{% endif %} {% if section.settings.product_images_position == 'right' %}mobile_only{% endif %}">
        {% include 'product-images' %}
      </div>

      <div class="{% if sidebar %}five{% else %}seven{% endif %} columns {% if section.settings.product_images_position == 'left' %}omega{% else %}alpha{% endif %}">

        {% assign collection_handles = product.collections | map: 'handle' %}
        {% assign variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}

        {% if settings.sale_banner_enabled and product.compare_at_price_max > product.price %}
          <div class="sale_banner_product">{{ 'collections.general.sale' | t }}</div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if collection_handles contains 'new' %}
          <div class="new_banner_product">{{ 'collections.general.new' | t }}</div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if collection_handles contains 'pre-order' %}
          <div class="new_banner_product">{{ 'collections.general.pre_order' | t }}</div>
        {% endif %}

         {% if section.settings.display_vendor %}
          <p class="vendor">
            <span itemprop="brand" class="vendor">{{ product.vendor | link_to_vendor }}</span>
          </p>
        {% endif %}

        {% if variant.sku != blank and section.settings.display_sku %}
          <p class="sku">
            <span itemprop="sku">{{ variant.sku }}</span>
          </p>
        {% endif %}
        <h1 class="product_name" itemprop="name">{{ product.title }}</h1>
        {% if settings.enable_shopify_product_badges and settings.enable_shopify_review_comments %}
          <span class="shopify-product-reviews-badge" data-id="{{ product.id }}"></span>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="feature_divider"></div>

        {% assign product_tags = product.tags | join: ' ' %}
        {% if product_tags contains 'meta-size-chart-' %}
          {% for tag in product.tags %}
            {% if tag contains 'meta-size-chart-' %}
              <a href="#size-chart{{product.id}}" class="size_chart" data-remodal-target="size-chart{{product.id}}" data-no-instant>{{ 'products.product.size_chart' | t }} <span class="icon-right-arrow"></span></a>
              {% include 'popup-size-chart', product_id: product.id %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        {% elsif settings.size_chart != blank %}
          <a href="#size-chart" class="size_chart" data-remodal-target="size-chart" data-no-instant>{{ 'products.product.size_chart' | t }} <span class="icon-right-arrow"></span></a>
        {% endif %}

        {% if collection_handles contains 'coming-soon' %}
          <p class="modal_price">{{ 'collections.general.coming_soon' | t }}</p>
        {% else %}
          <p class="modal_price" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="{{ shop.currency }}" />
            <meta itemprop="seller" content="{{ shop.name | escape }}" />
            <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/{% if variant.available %}InStock{% else %}OutOfStock{% endif %}">
            <meta itemprop="itemCondition" content="New" />

            <span class="sold_out">{% if variant.available == false %}{{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}{% endif %}</span>
            <span itemprop="price" content="{{ variant.price | money_without_currency }}" class="{% if variant.compare_at_price > variant.price %}sale{% endif %}">
              <span class="current_price {% if product.available == false %}hidden{% endif %}">
                {% if variant.price > 0 %}
                  <span class="money">{{ variant.price | money }}</span>
                {% else %}
                  {{ settings.free_price_text }}
                {% endif %}
              </span>
            </span>
            <span class="was_price">
            {% if variant.price < variant.compare_at_price and variant.available %}
              <span class="money">{{ variant.compare_at_price | money }}</span>
            {% endif %}
            </span>
          </p>

          {% include 'product-notify-me' %}
        {% endif %}

        {% unless collection_handles contains 'coming-soon' %}
          {% include 'product-form' with 'product' %}
        {% endunless %}

        {% if settings.enable_shopify_review_comments and settings.review_position == "next_to_gallery" %}
          <div id="shopify-product-reviews" data-id="{{product.id}}">{{ product.metafields.spr.reviews }}</div>
        {% endif %}

        {% if section.settings.display_collections or section.settings.display_tags or section.settings.display_type %}
          <div class="product_links">
            {% if settings.display_collections %}
              <p>
                <span class="label">{{ 'products.product.collections' | t }}:</span>
                <span>
                 {% for col in product.collections %}
                   <a href="{{ col.url }}" title="{{ col.title }}">{{ col.title }}</a>{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
                 {% endfor %}
                </span>
              </p>
            {% endif %}

            {% if section.settings.display_type %}
              <p>
                <span class="label">{{ 'products.product.product_types' | t }}:</span>
                <span>{{ product.type | link_to_type }}</span>
              </p>
            {% endif %}

            {% if section.settings.display_tags %}
              <p>
               {% for tag in product.tags %}
                 {% if forloop.first %}
                   <span class="label">{{ 'products.product.tags' | t }}:</span>
                 {% endif %}

                 {% unless tag contains 'meta-' %}
                   <span>
                     <a href="/collections/{% if collection %}{{ collection.handle }}{% else %}all{% endif %}/{{ tag | handle }}" title="{{ 'products.product.products_tagged' | t: tag: tag }}">{{ tag }}</a>{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
                     </span>
                 {% endunless %}
               {% endfor %}
              </p>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        {% endif %}

        <div class="meta">
          {% if section.settings.display_social_buttons %}
            {% include "social-buttons" with "product" %}
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>

      {% if section.settings.product_images_position == 'right' %}
        <div class="{% if sidebar %}seven{% else %}nine{% endif %} columns {% if product-images == blank %}{% if section.settings.product_images_position == 'left' %}alpha{% else %}omega{% endif %}{% endif %} mobile_hidden">
          {% include 'product-images' %}
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>

    <br class="clear" />
    <div class="section clearfix">
      <div class="description">
        {{ product.description }}
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    {% if settings.enable_shopify_review_comments and settings.review_position == "below_gallery" %}
      <div class="shopify-reviews">
        <div id="shopify-product-reviews" data-id="{{product.id}}">{{ product.metafields.spr.reviews }}</div>
      </div>
    {% endif %}

{% if section.settings.display_related_products and sidebar == false %}
    </div>
  </div>
  {% include 'related-products' %}
{% elsif section.settings.display_related_products and sidebar == true %}
      {% include 'related-products' %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% else %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}

{% schema %}

{
  "name": "Product bottom",
  "class": "product-template product-description-bottom-template",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "Product gallery"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "gallery_arrows",
      "label": "Show arrows on product gallery"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "activate_zoom",
      "label": "Magnify product images on hover"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "enable_product_lightbox",
      "label": "Enable product gallery popup",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "activate_autoplay",
      "label": "Enable product gallery slideshow"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "slideshow_animation",
      "label": "Gallery transition",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "slide",
          "label": "Slide"
        },
        {
          "value": "fade",
          "label": "Fade"
        }
      ],
      "default": "slide"
    },
    {
      "type": "radio",
      "id": "product_images_position",
      "label": "Gallery position",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "left",
          "label": "Left"
        },
        {
          "value": "right",
          "label": "Right"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "product_thumbs",
      "label": "Show product gallery thumbnails"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "thumbnail_position",
      "label": "Thumbnail position",
      "default": "bottom-thumbnails",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "left-thumbnails",
          "label": "Left"
        },
        {
          "value": "bottom-thumbnails",
          "label": "Bottom"
        },
        {
          "value": "right-thumbnails",
          "label": "Right"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "Product info"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "product_breadcrumb",
      "label": "Show breadcrumb links"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "display_vendor",
      "label": "Show vendor"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "display_sku",
      "label": "Show SKU"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "display_collections",
      "label": "Show collections"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "display_type",
      "label": "Show type"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "display_tags",
      "label": "Show tags"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "display_social_buttons",
      "label": "Show social media share icons",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "Related products"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "display_related_products",
      "label": "Show related products ([?](http:\/\/support.outofthesandbox.com\/customer\/portal\/articles\/942378-related-products))",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "radio",
      "id": "related_products_style",
      "label": "Layout",
      "default": "grid",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "slider",
          "label": "Slider"
        },
        {
          "value": "grid",
          "label": "Grid"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "related_products_limit",
      "label": "Product limit",
      "default": "12",
    "options": [
        {
          "value": "3",
          "label": "3"
        },
        {
          "value": "4",
          "label": "4"
        },
        {
          "value": "5",
          "label": "5"
        },        
        {
          "value": "6",
          "label": "6"
        },                
        {
          "value": "8",
          "label": "8"
        },
        {
          "value": "10",
          "label": "10"
        },        
        {
          "value": "12",
          "label": "12"
        },
        {
          "value": "15",
          "label": "15"
        },        
        {
          "value": "20",
          "label": "20"
        },                
        {
          "value": "24",
          "label": "24"
        },
        {
          "value": "48",
          "label": "48"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "products_per",
      "label": "Products per row",
      "default": "3",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "3",
          "label": "3"
        },
        {
          "value": "4",
          "label": "4"
        },
        {
          "value": "5",
          "label": "5"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "Sidebar"
    },
    {
      "type": "paragraph",
      "content": "Create a sidebar by adding content blocks."
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "toggle",
      "label": "Toggle sidebar content"
    }
  ],
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "filter_by_tag",
      "name": "Tag list",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "content": "Will not display if there are no tags associated with product."
        }
      ],
      "limit": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "filter_by_collection",
      "name": "Collection list",
      "limit": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "filter_by_type",
      "name": "Type list",
      "limit": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "filter_by_vendor",
      "name": "Vendor list",
      "limit": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "menu",
      "name": "Menu",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "link_list",
          "id": "custom_menu_linklist",
          "label": "Menu"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "name": "Text",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "title",
          "label": "Heading",
          "default": "Heading"
        },
        {
          "type": "richtext",
          "id": "text",
          "label": "Text",
          "default": "<p>Text area can be used for special announcements or general information.</p>"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "page",
      "name": "Page",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "page",
          "id": "content_page",
          "label": "Page"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "default": {
    "settings": {

    }
  }
}

{% endschema %}

{% assign option_name = 'Color' %}

{% if product.options contains option_name %}

<script>
// Grabbing product thumbnails
// Covers: Editions, Launchpad Star, Lookbook, Kickstand, Startup, Simple, Radiance, Minimal, Supply, New Standard and many more.
var thumbnails = jQuery('img[src*="/products/"]') /* All product images */
  .not('#related-products img')                   /* Except related products, thumbnails not clickable */
  .not('a[href^="/collections/"] img')            /* Except related products */
  .not('a[href^="/products/"] img')               /* Except mini-cart products */
  .not('header img')                              /* Except mini-cart products, thumbnails not clickable */
  .not('#drawer img')                             /* Except mini-cart products, thumbnails not clickable, in Simple theme. */
  .not(':first');                                 /* Except first one, i.e the main image */
  
var optionSelect; 
{% assign option_index = 0 %}  
{% for option in product.options %}
  {% if option == option_name %}
    {% assign option_index = forloop.index0 %}  
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
  
{% if product.options.size == 1 %}
  optionSelect = '.single-option-selector';
{% else %}
  optionSelect = 'label:contains({{ option_name }}) + .single-option-selector';   
{% endif %}
  
jQuery('form[action="/cart/add"]').on('change', optionSelect, function() {
  var optionValue = $(this).val();
  thumbnails.each(function() {
    var wrapper = $(this);
    while ( wrapper.parent().children().length === 1 ) {
      wrapper = wrapper.parent();
    }
    if ( jQuery(this).attr('alt') === optionValue ) {
      wrapper.show();
    }
    else {
      wrapper.hide();
    }
  });
});    
</script>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: you need to change the selectors, it's hard to us help you without all the product-template

Comment: Makes sense. Diving in again now.  If I figure it out I'll be sure to post the answer. I added the the code for template used on the product I'm experimenting with.  Thanks for taking a look. 
@sullivanv

Comment: Also, just to help clarify, I am using the an option named "Color" with the alt text matching variant names.